# how show scrollbar over the purple card and show only when user scroll in React.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs

How to show scroll only when user scroll and show scroll over the purple card just with specific design like in the image below

[The design i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKEic.png)

[This is what i have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaByA.png)

I want to get rid of that white part in the right hand and want to scroll over the cards

here is code of that div

```
 mainDiv:{
    width:'400px',
    minWidth:'400px',
    height: 'calc(100vh - 90px)',
    maxHeight: 'calc(100vh - 90px)',
    overflowY:'auto',
    display:'flex',
    flexDirection:'column',
    margin:'10px 0px 0px 0px',
    borderRadius:'10px',
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    boxShadow:'0px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
    "&::-webkit-scrollbar": {
        width: '11px'
    },
    scrollbarWidth: 'thin',
    scrollbarColor: '#000',
    "&::-webkit-scrollbar-track": {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    },
    "&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
        backgroundColor:  '#000',
        borderRadius: '6px',
        border: '3px solid #000',
    }

},
```

Comment: it's hard to help you without code sample

Comment: @kurohige i updated the question please view